# WC_Order items empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

this is very strange, i am calling `$order = new WC_Order(52);` and I get a correct order object but the Items array is empty.

Any ideas whats going wrong ?

I am using WooCommerce 3.4.3.

Comment: Try: select * from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id=52;

Comment: I 've tried it and I get a result of 2 rows, one line item and one shipping item, which is correct for this order

Comment: Do you know how to use a PHP debugger? If so try putting a breakpoint at WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store::read() in the file includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-item-product-data-store.php. This is where the data for a product order item is read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also thought what you are doing should work but in fact it is wrong. I read the WooCommerce source code and this is how WooCommerce does it.

```
if ( ! $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ) {
    return;
}
$order_items = $order->get_items( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_order_item_types', 'line_item' ) );
```

The $order->get_items() call will check if the line item has been read from the data store and read it if it has not yet been read. So, new WC_Order(52) actually only partially initializes the order object. The order items are initialized later when they are accessed through the order. This may be more efficient as items that are not used will not be initialized. Please note that the order is created by using the wc_get_order() function. You should do this instead of new WC_Order() as this uses the factory to create the order.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided here is correct. However if you are trying to get the order items on `woocommerce_new_order` it will not solve your problem since line items are assigned to the order after the `woocommerce_new_order` hook is triggered.

I only managed to sort my issues after I changed the hook to `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` as per below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'get_order_items_on_checkout', 50, 3 );
function get_order_items_on_checkout($order_id, $posted_data, $order){
   $items = $order->get_items();
}
```

Comment: It's possible the get the items in the `woocommerce_new_order` hook, but then you need to use the `$order` 2nd variable passed to the hook function.  Using the `wc_get_order` function in the hook won't work.